# Is the action by conjugation of $S_5$ on its six $5$-Sylow subgroups faithful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, sylow-theory

> Is the action by conjugation of $S_5$ on its six $5$-Sylow subgroups faithful?

I can see how the second Sylow theorem makes this action transitive.

I am not sure how to check whether it's faithful, without actually doing the computations.

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3307911/305862

Comment: Good catch! (although too sophisticated to be considered as a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_5$ is simple and cannot be the kernel.

Comment: I am ready to delete this answer if someone finds a duplicate (I did not succeed in finding any).